# How to re-use my existing Google Analytics Reporting API V4 Python script to authenticate Google Analytics Data API (GA4)?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have been using a GA Reporting API V4 Python script to authenticate report pulls but I am trying to re-use the script to authenticate GA4 API now but I am getting the following error and I am not able to find the root cause.

Error: Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields refresh_token, client_secret.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import csv
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import ast
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'client_secrets_services.json'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  """
  credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
  
  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsdata', 'v1beta', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics

def get_report(analytics, start_date, end_date_delta):
  """Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.

  Args:
    analytics: An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
  Returns:
    The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  return analytics.properties().batchRunReports(property='properties/3220*****',
      body={
        'requests': [
        {
          'limit': 100000,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") , 'endDate': (start_date+end_date_delta).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}],           
           'metrics': [ {'name': 'screenPageViews'} ],
           'dimensions': [{'name':'date'}, {'name':'sessionSourceMedium'},  {'name':'pagePath'} ],
           'dimensionFilter': [
                                {"filters": [ {"dimensionName": "pagePath",
                                              "operator": "REGEXP",
                                              "expressions": "/pharmacysuccess"}]
               }]
      }]
      }
  ).execute()

def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.

  Args:
    response: An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print(header + ': ', dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print('Date range:', str(i))
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print(metricHeader.get('name') + ':', value)

def main():
  final_data = pd.DataFrame()
  start_date = date(2023, 1, 1)
  end_date = date(2023, 2, 1)
  delta = timedelta(days=2)
  end_date_delta = timedelta(days=1)
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  while start_date < end_date:
    response = get_report(analytics,start_date, end_date_delta)
    columns = []
    for s in range(len(response['reports'][0]['columnHeader']['dimensions'])):
        columns.append(response['reports'][0]['columnHeader']['dimensions'][s])
    for s in range(len(response['reports'][0]['columnHeader']['metricHeader']['metricHeaderEntries'])):
        columns.append(response['reports'][0]['columnHeader']['metricHeader']['metricHeaderEntries'][s]['name'])
    while response['reports'][0]['data'].get("rows") is not None:
        dimensions = []
        for s in range(len(response['reports'][0]['data']['rows'])):
            dimensions.append(response['reports'][0]['data']['rows'][s]['dimensions'] )
        metrics = []
        for s in range(len(response['reports'][0]['data']['rows'])):
            metrics.append(response['reports'][0]['data']['rows'][s]['metrics'][0]['values'])
        rows=[]
        for i in range(len(dimensions)):
            rows.append(dimensions[i] + metrics[i])
        response_final = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
        final_data=final_data.append(response_final,ignore_index=True)
        break
    start_date+=delta
  print(final_data)
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: The Google Analytics Reporting API V4 does not support Google Analytics 4 (GA4) properties. Use the [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) to access the new reporting features for GA4 properties.

Comment: I have not moved to GA4 yet but it looks like when you call the `BetaAnalyticsDataClient()` function you will need to create a `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable or pass your own credentials to the function's optional [credentials param](https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-data/blob/8afd7c45c0703b5bed2f9e555ce9b01aefa58aa7/google/analytics/data_v1beta/services/beta_analytics_data/client.py#L337)

Comment: Thank you, @It_is_Chris. That helped me get a direction. When using the google-analytics-data package, I am continuously getting an import error: 
"ImportError: cannot import name 'exceptions' from 'google.api_core' (C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\google\api_core\__init__.py)". Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot seem to replicate that issue by doing `from google.api_core import exceptions as core_exceptions` Try creating a virtual environment using conda or virtualenv, activate the newly created environment, `pip install google-analytics-data` in the new environment, and try again.